# Inserting a non-simple inline ASM instruction using LLVM IRBuilder

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have been trying to perform simple instrumentation of inline assembly instruction after the `mmap` function using the `IRBuilder` class.

For example, using `C`, I can program such thing as this:

```
// test.c
#define orr_test(ptr) ({                       \
  uint64_t __result;                    \
  asm volatile (\
    "orr %0, %1, #4 << 60\n"\
    : "=r" (__result) : "r" (ptr)); \
  __result;                     \
})

int main() {
  char *a = mmap(0, sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  a = orr_test(a);
  printf("%p\n", a);
}
```

To summarize my question, I am trying to implement the above function in the LLVM IR level using LLVM IRBuilder, but facing a bit of a problem.

I can do instrumentation of inline assembly for a straightforward inline assembly instruction. Still, it becomes challenging when I'm trying to do it for a bit more complicated instruction.

Here is my implementation of instrumenting an inline assembly instruction in the LLVM after finding the `mmap` function:

```
void instrumentMmap(llvm::BasicBlock &BB) {
    bool instrument = false;
    LLVMContext& context = BB.getContext();
    for (auto &Inst : BB) {
        if (auto storeI = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(&Inst)) {
            IRBuilder<> builder(storeI);
            for (auto &operand : Inst.operands()){
                if (auto callI = dyn_cast<CallInst>(operand)) {
                    if (callI->getCalledFunction()->getName() == "mmap") {       
                        instrument = true;      
                    }

                    if (instrument == true) {
                        Value* v = storeI->getPointerOperand();
                        Type* ptrType = v->getType()->getPointerElementType();
                        errs() << *v << "\n"; // THIS IS THE VALUE I NEED TO PASS AS AN ARGUMENT 
                                              // TO INSTRUMENTED INLINE ASSEMBLY
                        builder.SetInsertPoint(&BB, ++builder.GetInsertPoint());
                        StringRef asmString = "swi #0";
                        StringRef constraints = "~{dirflag},~{fpsr},~{flags}";
                        InlineAsm *IA = llvm::InlineAsm::get(FunctionType::get(Type::getVoidTy(context), false), asmString, constraints, true, false, InlineAsm::AD_ATT);
                        ArrayRef<Value *> Args = None;
                        llvm::CallInst *Ptr = builder.CreateCall(IA,Args);
                        Ptr->addAttribute(AttributeList::FunctionIndex, Attribute::NoUnwind);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This results in an LLVM IR such as this (you can see there is a `call` instruction added after `store i8*` instruction):

```
...
19:                                               ; preds = %15
  %20 = load i64, i64* %2, align 8, !dbg !273
  %21 = call i8* @mmap(i8* null, i64 %20, i32 35, i32 34, i32 -1, i64 0) #4, !dbg !274
  store i8* %21, i8** %4, align 8, !dbg !275
  call void asm sideeffect "swi #0", "~{dirflag},~{fpsr},~{flags}"() #4, !dbg !276
  %22 = load i8*, i8** %4, align 8, !dbg !276
...
```

The reason why I'm instrumenting an inline assembly instruction **after** `store` instruction is that from my understanding, I will need to use an updated `i8** %4` address value after the `mmap` function completes. So the updated address value after `mmap` allocates a memory will be the one that will be used to apply inline assembly instructions (e.g., `orr %0, %0, #4 << 60` where `%0` would equate to a value stored in `i8** %4`).

So how should I go about doing this? I have found many references (https://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/ir/ir-builder.html) which provides an example as shown below that is closest to answering my question:

```
fty = FunctionType(IntType(64), [IntType(64),IntType(64)])
add = builder.asm(fty, "mov $2, $0\nadd $1, $0", "=r,r,r",
                  (arg_0, arg_1), True, name="asm_add")
```

However, this example also raises a few questions as I'm not too sure what should be `arg_0` or `arg_1`, are they supposed to be `LLVM::Value?` and as for `FunctionType`, how should one go about defining such `FunctionType` for an instruction such as `MRS`? (https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289881054.htm)

I apologize for the long post, so please let me know if anything is unclear. I would very much appreciate it if anyone has a good example of how `inlineASM` class is used for the `LLVM`.

Comment: llvmlite is a python binding for llvm. so you can't use 'builder.asm' in your BasicBlock pass.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MeB7Dp3G2UE

Comment: @harry Hello! Sorry for the late reply, I have checked your link and it provided a decent reference. I think I still need to probably do a lot more test/trial (as they stated in the video, it is quite perplexing to work with inline ASM with LLVM), but the video indeed provided nice information. I hope to see more videos like this in the future! Thank you for your link.